# binary search tree using rand

Tags: random, binary-tree

i am trying to create a binary search tree with 50 random variables, i wrote a code but the random variables are not being declared..please help me out

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
```

//creating a class node which contains value,rvalue which stores the value pointed by  rlink and  lvalue which stores the value pointed by  llink

```
class node


{
private:
int value;
int rvalue;
int lvalue;
node *rlink;
node *llink;

public:

void insertnode(node*,int);
node *create(node*,int); 

};



void node::insertnode(node *h,int k)

{

h=new node;
h->value=k;
h->rlink=NULL;
h->llink=NULL;
h->rvalue=0;
h->lvalue=0;

}


node *node::create(node*root, int i)

{

int A[i];
for(int j=0; j<i; j++) {
    A[j]=rand()%1000;  //stores random values in array
    cout<<A[j];

}
node *k;
node *h;
insertnode(root, A[0]);

cout<<h->value;

for (int j=1; j<i; j++) {
    if(A[j]<h->value){
        if(h->llink==NULL) {
            insertnode(k, A[j]);
            h->lvalue=k->value;

        }
        h->llink=k;
    }
    else if(A[j]>h->value)
    {
        if(h->rlink==NULL) {
            insertnode(k, A[j]);
            h->rvalue=k->value;

        }
        h->rlink=k;

    }


} 

return root;


}


int main()

{


int i;
cout<<"enter the number of elements in a matix";
cin>>i;
node s;
node *h;
h=s.create(h,i);

}
```

Comment: You should tag your question with the relevant language (C or C++ I assume).

Answer (score 0):

in the function create(), you are using variables k and h which are pointers to node. But you have not initialized this variables and also you have not allocated space for those pointers. First allocate memory to this variables.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few problems with your code.

- To create a node should just create a new node for a given value (this should be done with a constructor. The other values in the node class will be initialized when the node is inserted in to the tree)
- To insert a node you should always be passing the root of the tree (or a reference to the tree itself) and the node to insert and then finding where to insert the node in the insert method (This can also be where you do aeny balancing if necessary)
- If you use the tree approach (which I would recommend) the tree should have a reference to it's root and possibly a count of the nodes in it
- To generate random nodes there is no use in using an array you should just get a new random value, create a node for it, and insert that into the list

To do the last part of this do something like (assuming C++)

```
int main() { 
  Tree *tree = new Tree(); //This creates a tree (you will need to create a tree class with a constructor
  int total = 50; //This the number of nodes you want store this however is necessary
  ....
  srand(time(NULL));
  for(int i = 0; i < total; i++) {
     int val = rand() % 1000 + 1; //This gets a number between 1-1000
     Node *node = new Node(val); //This constructs the node (write this constructor)
     tree.insertNode(node); //This will insert the node into the tree (write this method)
  }
  ....
}
```

This would create a tree with 50 values assuming the constructor for Node and Tree and the insertNode method words